# Android fill listView with custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to fill my listView with a custom array adapter I created. The result I want is to have an image on the left hand side, and two labels on the right.

When I reach the fragment that should display the listView, the app crashes but I can't really find out why. The error being `java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()`.

Here is my code:

The fragment:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().setTitle("Inbox");

    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_layout, container, false);

    ListView list = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.listViewMyAccount);
    inboxCellElement[] elts = new inboxCellElement[] {new inboxCellElement(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera, "Val", "Hi !")};
    list.setAdapter(new inboxCellAdapter(new NavDrawer(), R.layout.inbox_cell_layout, elts, (NavDrawer) getActivity()));

    return myView; 
}
```

The Object containing the data to pass to the listView:

```
public class inboxCellElement {
  private String name = "", message = "";
  private int imgId = 0;

  public inboxCellElement(int imgId, String name, String message){
      this.imgId = imgId;
      this.name = name;
      this.message = message;
  }

  public int getImgId() { return imgId; }
  public String getName() { return name; }
  public String getMessage() { return message; }
}
```

The custom Adapter:

```
public class inboxCellAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
  inboxCellElement[] elts;
  NavDrawer navDrawer;

  // constructor
  public inboxCellAdapter(Context context, int resource, Object[] objects, NavDrawer navDrawer) {
      super(context, resource, objects);
      elts = (inboxCellElement[]) objects;
      this.navDrawer = navDrawer;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      MyHolder holder = null;
      LayoutInflater inflater = new NavDrawer().getLayoutInflater();
      if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_cell_layout, null, false);
          holder = new MyHolder(convertView);
          convertView.setTag(holder);
      }
      else {
          holder = (MyHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }
      holder.getUpperText().setText(elts[position].getName());
      holder.getLowerText().setText(elts[position].getMessage());
      holder.getImage().setImageResource(elts[position].getImgId());

      return convertView;
  }

  private class MyHolder {
      private View row;
      private TextView upperText = null, lowerText = null;
      private ImageView img = null;

      public MyHolder(View row) {
          this.row = row;
      }

      public TextView getUpperText() {
          if (this.upperText == null) {
              this.upperText = (TextView) navDrawer.findViewById(R.id.inboxCellName);
          }
          return this.upperText;
      }

      public TextView getLowerText() {
          if (this.lowerText == null) {
              this.lowerText = (TextView) navDrawer.findViewById(R.id.inboxCellMessage);
          }
          return this.lowerText;
      }

      public ImageView getImage() {
          if (this.img == null) {
              this.img = (ImageView) navDrawer.findViewById(R.id.inboxCellImg);
          }
          return this.img;
      }
   }
}
```

It seems that the error comes from the several `navDrawer.findViewById(...)` calls, but I have no idea how to fix it. Can anyone confirm the error happens here, why and help me fixing it ? Thanks

EDIT: Adding the stacktrace

--------- beginning of crash

```
04-12 14:32:58.816 2128-2128/t2g.com.travel2gather E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: t2g.com.travel2gather, PID: 2128
                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5253)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:229)
                                                                         at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:178)
                                                                         at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:137)
                                                                         at t2g.com.travel2gather.adapters.inboxCellAdapter.<init>(inboxCellAdapter.java:0)
                                                                         at t2g.com.travel2gather.inboxFragment.onCreateView(inboxFragment.java:30)
                                                                         at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
                                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
                                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
                                                                         at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
                                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
                                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: can you post full stack trace?

Comment: I added it at the end of the post

Comment: Are you anywhere calling `getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);`?

Comment: What is this `NavDrawer`?

Comment: No, Could this help getting the current context ? And the navDrawer is my main activity that contains a NavigationDrawer, hence the use of fragments.

Comment: How can its constructor provide context?

Comment: `list.setAdapter(new inboxCellAdapter(new NavDrawer(), R.layout.inbox_cell_layout, elts, (NavDrawer) getActivity()));` it should called as `list.setAdapter(new inboxCellAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.inbox_cell_layout, elts, (NavDrawer) getActivity()));`

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to replace the first `new NavDrawer()` thanks. The app still crashes but for another reason.

Comment: Why do you need to create activity's instance btw?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108943/discussion-between-rohit-arya-and-dliix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Activity's constructor to provide `context` (as you said in comments `NavDrawer` is your `MainActivity`). So change this `onCreateView` like this.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().setTitle("Inbox");

    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_layout, container, false);

    ListView list = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.listViewMyAccount);
    inboxCellElement[] elts = new inboxCellElement[] {new inboxCellElement(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera, "Val", "Hi !")};
    list.setAdapter(new inboxCellAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.inbox_cell_layout, elts, (NavDrawer) getActivity()));

    return myView; 
}
```

Similarly in you adapter:

```
public class inboxCellAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
  inboxCellElement[] elts;
  NavDrawer navDrawer;
  Activity activity;

  // constructor
  public inboxCellAdapter(Activity activity, int resource, Object[] objects, NavDrawer navDrawer) {
      super(context, resource, objects);
      this.activity = activity;
      elts = (inboxCellElement[]) objects;
      this.navDrawer = navDrawer;
  }
```

Hence `getView` will be like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   MyHolder holder = null;
   LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I understand why this happens. I think you made a mistake by calling `super(context, resource, objects);` since we removed the variable `context`. However, I replaced it by `activity`, but I still have a crash: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at t2g.com.travel2gather.adapters.inboxCellAdapter.getView(inboxCellAdapter.java:42)`.  Why is `holder.getUpperText()` null?

Comment: EDIT: I found the error: In the holder i was using `activity.findViewById()` instead of `row.findViewById()` Thanks for the help !

Comment: Great! Happy coding. :)